# Can Enunciate generate docs for an API that handles generic types?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, enunciate

Given an abstract, generic Resource class and a concrete implementation:

```
public abstract class AbstractResource<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService<T> service;

    @Path("/{id}")
    @GET
    public T get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return service.get(id);
    }
}

@Path("/people")
public class PersonResource extends AbstractResource<Person> { }
```

It appears that when generating the docs for `PersonResource`, Enunciate is not picking up the fact that `get()` returns a `Person`.

1. Person is not listed in the Data Model > Data Types section.
2. Under the GET section, Response Body shows the element type as "(custom)".

Are these issues because of the use of generics as the entity types? Is there a way to hint to Enunciate what the real types are so the documentation can be generated correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is `Person` annotated as `@XmlRootElement`? If so, is it included in the same project as `PersonResource`? If not, are you importing the `Person` class as described in [Enunciate: Multi-Module Projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Multi-Module+Projects)?